# Why does Char have an instance for Bounded?

Tags: haskell

Why is there a `maxBound` of `Char`?  If `Char` is character then why it is explained by numbers, and if it is not a number what does it mean?

```
> maxBound :: Char
'\1114111'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All characters, like all things in a computer, are ultimately just numbers. [`Char`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.4.1/html/libraries/base/Data-Char.html) represents [unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), which are represented via numbers. You can convert between `Char` and `Int` values with `ord` and `chr`. E.g. the unicode value for `a` is 97, so `ord 'a'` is `97` and `chr 97` is `'a'`.

`Char '\1114111'` is the `Char` that represents the number `1114111`, or 0x10FFFF, which is [defined](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) as a noncharacter. This is the largest value that is defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), and is the largest that Haskell supports: `'\1114112'` will cause a compile error.

Answer (score 4):

Character encodings are tricky. Behind the scenes, all characters are represented by numbers. The Unicode standard provides a set of "code points" which are simply numbers which map to a particular sequence of real characters. Unicode defines code points between 0 and 1114111 and so that's what you see when you try `maxBound`.

`Char` encodes Unicode code points as individual integers, which is somewhat inefficient. If you want an efficient encoding, use `Text`.

You're seeing `\1114111` displayed because that's the code point that `maxBound :: Char` represents and there is no more efficient, meaningful way to display it. In particular, it's in the "Supplementary Private Use Area-B" of the Unicode standard which means that it's reserved for use outside of the scope of Unicode and thus has no standard meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The `Char` data type represents Unicode values.  These values are stored in the computer as numbers, and each number as a specific representation on the screen.  For `Char`, the minimum value is `0` and the maximum value is `1114111`.

An easier example is C in which the `char` type is equivalent to a 7-bit number corresponding to the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table of characters and they can range in value from 0 to 127, although I believe it is legal to store an entire 8-bit byte in a `char`, giving you the values 0 through 255.

Remember, everything is a number to a computer.  Some data types have representations that can be ordered and are finite, so they have a minimum value and a maximum value.

An example of a data type in Haskell that does not have a minimum or maximum value is `Integer`, since it can represent any integer value so long as you have enough RAM available.

Comment: A subset of unicode values? Unicode is defined as going up to `0x10ffff` and that's what `Char` does too. If anything, it's a superset of valid unicode codepoints, because it includes the invalid "marker" range reserved for UTF-16 cotninuations.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to look at the source of the `Bounded Char` instance itself. Characters are effectively numbers with representation and the bounds represent the bounds of the Unicode code points.

```
instance Bounded Char where
    minBound  =  '\0'
    maxBound  =  '\xffff'
```